# BST (Binary Search Tree) reverse level-order traversal isn't giving me the correct answer/result

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I really need your help with this exercise about binary search tree. I have to reverse the order of traversal from down to up and from left to right along the way. This is the exercise:

> Given a BST, write a function that will return a list of values. Elements at the last depth of the tree will appear first in the output list. The elements at the previous depth level will appear next, all the way to the root. Elements at the same depth will appear in the list from smallest to largest.
>
> > elements_in_bst_by order(tree_node)# returns a list

> For example, if we created a BST using the values inserted in the following order *2, 1, 3, 0* would return this list *[0, 1, 3, 2]*

If you didn't understand I'll explain it this way:

> ```
>             2          root level 0
>           1   3        children level 1
>         0              children level 2
> ```
>
> this should return 0 then 1 then 3 then finally 2 (root)

This is the module given in the exercise (it contains the Binary Search Tree code, PS: using this module is mandatory):

```
class TreeNode(object):
    """A tree node with two children trees"""

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def search(self, value):
        """Search in a BST"""
        if self.data is None:
            return None

        if self.data == value:
            return self

        if value < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                return None
            return self.left.search(value)

        else:
            if self.right is None:
                return None
            return self.right.search(value)

    def insert(self, value):
        """insert a node in a BST"""
        if self.data is None:
            self.data = value
            return

        if value < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = TreeNode(value, self)
            else:
                self.left.insert(value)

        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = TreeNode(value, self)
            else:
                self.right.insert(value)
```

This is my code:

```
import bst

def preorder(root, level, dict):

    # base case: empty tree
    if root is None:
        return
    
    # insert current node and its level into the dict
    dict.setdefault(level, []).append(root.data)
    
    # recur for left and right subtree by increasing level by 1
    if root.left is not None:
        preorder(root.left,level + 1, dict)
    if root.right is not None:    
        preorder(root.right,level + 1, dict)
    
    
    # Recursive function to do reverse level order traversal of given binary tree
def tree_levels(tree):
    list = []
    # create an empty dict to store nodes between given levels
    dict = {}
    
    # traverse the tree and insert its nodes into the dict
    # corresponding to the their level
    preorder(tree, 0, dict)
    
    # iterate through the dict in reverse order and
    # print all nodes present in very level
    for i in range(0,len(dict)):
        list.append(dict[i])
    newest = [i[0] for i in list]
    return newest
root = TreeNode(4)
root.insert(5)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(1)
tree_levels(root)
```

It's giving me this error:

> **list differ: [2,1] != [1,2]**

> **Expected: [2,1]**

> **Actual: [1,2]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have (finally) solved the problem, after 5 hours of trying different solutions I returned to this one and corrected it. This is the correct code:

```
import bst

def preorder(root, level, dict):
    
        # base case: empty tree
        if root is None:
            return
        
        # insert current node and its level into the dict
        dict.setdefault(level, []).append(root.data)
        
        # recur for left and right subtree by increasing level by 1
        if root.left is not None:
            preorder(root.left, level + 1, dict)
        if root.right is not None:    
            preorder(root.right , level + 1, dict)
        
        # Recursive function to do reverse level order traversal of given binary tree
def tree_levels(tree):
        list = []
        # create an empty dict to store nodes between given levels
        dict = {}
        
        # traverse the tree and insert its nodes into the dict
        # corresponding to the their level
        preorder(tree, 0, dict)
        
        # iterate through the dict in reverse order and
        # print all nodes present in very level
        for i in range(len(dict)-1,-1,-1):
            list += dict[i]
        return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Just creat a simple preorder traversal, using a queue.

```py
from queue import Queue
def preorder(root):
    ans = []
    q = Queue()
    q.put(root)
    while not q.empty():
        temp = []
        n = q.qsize()
        while n:
            x = q.get()
            n-=1
            temp.append(x.data)
            if x.left:
                q.put(x.left)
            if x.right:
                q.put(x.right)
        ans.append(temp)
    print(ans[::-1])   # prints [[1], [2], [3, 5], [4]] for your example
```

Comment: I wish I could but no I'm restricted to using the 'bst' module + I have to put them in a list not to print them and also I can't put multiple lists inside a list hence why I utilized this to remove brackets:       
    newest = [i[0] for i in list]
    return newest

Comment: Oh, you should've added that using the ```bst``` module is a must